# XML Schema regex for integer range, excluding 0

Tags: xml, regex, schema

I'm developing an XML schema and I need to restrict an integer to being within a ranger of -20 to 20, but not 0.

I was going to use minInclusive and maxInclusive for the -20 to 20.

I tried to add the regex "="^(?!0).+", but that does not appear to be a valid XML regex.

What value can I put in for xs:pattern that will prevent an integer from being 0?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enumerating the legal values. Workable since the range is quite small.

Comment: I am sure that would work, but I would rather implement it more cleanly.  That's for the response, though.

Answer (score 0):

Simple lack of escape character.  The pattern value should have read "^(\?!0).+".